# MYSQL: Delete a record from all the tables in a single shot

Tags: mysql

i am having a `mysql` database, and in one `table` i have `f_id`  as `P_Key` and this `f_id` is referenced in multiple `table` as `f_key`. and i want to delete the records of this `f_id`(let say 10) from all the `table` in a once. then for this i need to `delete` in all the `table` which are having `f_id`= 10 as `f_key` then only i can `delete` this from the main `table` which contains it as a `P_Key`. can  there be any automated process which can `delete` this by automatic looking into the `table` ,I dont want to write down the whole list of the `table`(as the list is very big more than 18 tables) in the query as this `p_key` is referenced in many `tables`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is set up an [ON DELETE CASCADE CONSTRAINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on your keys such that on deletion of records on your parent table will delete all child records in your other tables that reference that row. Note that you'll need to delete the foreign keys and and add them again if they don't have an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint. Something like this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE [table_name]

ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP FOREIGN KEY [f_id];

ALTER TABLE [table_name]
ADD CONSTRAINT [f_id]
FOREIGN KEY (`[f_id]`) REFERENCES `[other_table]` (`[column_name]`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: thnx a lot for this, i did it in all the tables but accidently 2 tables were left , added CASCADE and i am done..thnks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to look into the `information_schema` tables to find out the names of your tables. Something like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "database_name"
```

replace `database_name` with the name of the database you want to inspect, and it should return all the table names. You might be able to do something with that list.

Comment: Yes, but also it will give me all the table names but still i need to look for the f_id in the table for checking and then only i can frame the query, but all i wanted is that DB should look on my behalf where this f_id is present and then delete.